# Weird System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

Tags: vb.net

Visual Studio 2017 Community, VB.NET, Windows7

**This is what I get**:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: '[FireDAC][DatS]-32. Variable length column [Version] overflow. Value length - [71], column maximum length - [10]'
```

**Details**:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException occurred
  HResult=0x80020009
  Message=[FireDAC][DatS]-32. Variable length column [Version] overflow. Value length - [71], column maximum length - [10]
  Source=AllSkyPlateSolver.PlateSolver
  StackTrace:
at AllSkyPlateSolver.IPlateSolver.PlateSolve(String FileName, Int32 FocalLength, Double PixelSize, Double CurrentRA, Double CurrentDec, Double NearRadius)
at WindowsApp1.ASCOM_Test3.Solve(String sPAR) in C:\Programming\VB\PatsAstroUtility\WindowsApp1\ASCOM_Test3.vb:line 233
at WindowsApp1.ASCOM_Test3.btnSolve_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Programming\VB\PatsAstroUtility\WindowsApp1\ASCOM_Test3.vb:line 208
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
at WindowsApp1.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in :line 81
```

**The weird thing**:
I did a complete re-installation of AllSkyPlateSolver. After that, I was able to call it just one single time and it did do what expected (plate solving of an image). Any time after that, I get this error. Even weirder: After I got the error in Visual Basic, I cannot start the original AllSkyPlateSolver from my desktop anymore without getting the same error.
Any advice would be appreciated.

**The relevant code**:

```
Private myASPS As AllSkyPlateSolver.PlateSolver
Private FocalLength As Integer = 570
Private PixelSize As Double = 5.4
Private CurrentRA As Double = tRA
Private CurrentDec As Double = tDE
Private NearRadius As Double = 15

Private Sub Solve()
    ImageFile = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
    myASPS = New AllSkyPlateSolver.PlateSolver()
    myASPS.PlateSolve(ImageFile, FocalLength, PixelSize, CurrentRA, CurrentDec, NearRadius)
End Sub
```

Comment: Just a guess, but perhaps PlateSolver is not terminating.  Try using TaskManager to see if it is running.  Does rebooting the PC clear the issue until you run the code again?

Comment: Nothing left in TaskManager. Reboot does not help. Only re-installation. I had a look into the registry, but could not find anything strange there either. The registry is my best guess though. I might dump the registry entry and compare after re-install and after VB-run. I was hoping somebody could interpret the error I get...

Comment: The error is in the library code.  If you do a search on the message `[FireDAC][DatS]-32. Variable length column [Version] overflow`, you should find that it is a database error where the code is trying to store a variable length string longer than is allowed by the DB field.  It is probably best to contact the library provider to report issue.  Another guess is that it may be related to the length of the file path passed to the method; is that length 71 by chance?

Comment: Thanks a lot TnTinMn for your helpful remarks! Changing the path to the image does not help. I tried to contact the author of ASPS but he doesn't respond. Making the situation even more complicated, he apparently uses a solver routine of yet another party (astrometry.net). I thinks that's where the database call takes place. I might try to figure out, if I can use that database from my own app... I guess I'm not there yet! :-) Thanks again. Your comments were very much appreciated!